# Looking for a movie of about futuristic city and alien society

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction, comedy, action

I can't describe the title well.So, maybe it's a bit confusing. Anyway, I am looking for this movie. I watched it maybe around 10-15 years ago. These are what I know about it:

**Year     :** I guess it's from late 80's to late 90's. It's not black and white

**Genre:** Sci-fi. Some comedy and action. Not animated

**Plot:**
The movie sets far in the future. Alien is not an usual thing there. There are a lot of hi-tech things, from flying cars to a battleships. There is a spaceship war going on and the enemy looking for a specific thing/person. The protagonist works as a courier(?). There's also a scene of which  aliens visiting pyramids (I think it's in the beginning of the movie). There's a blue haired black guy that works as a MC. There's a shoot out during the show and an alien singer is killed.

Comment: Sounds like The Fifth Element 1997: does this Alien singer look familiar: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4MR6D7tL38U

Comment: I agree this sounds like The Fifth Element. The black MC guy (played by Chris Tucker) has blonde hair, but other than that, the description fits this movie.

Comment: So, who is the blue haired black guy from my memory? :D

Comment: The blue haired black guy that works as an MC? That is probably Ruby Rhod, played by Chris Tucker. He doesn't have blue hair, but his hair is a prominent feature. Here is an image: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119116/mediaviewer/rm3293500928

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the movie **[The Fifth Element](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119116/)** 1997 starring Bruce Willis.

It features flying cars/ Aliens and lots of futuristic tech. It has a scene at the beginning where Aliens visit a Pyramid to collect the Elements as they are not safe on Earth anymore.

Also the Alien singer scene below matches your question:

Comment: who played this alien singer?

Comment: Her name is Maïwenn:  http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0494069/

Comment: Congratulations on winning the contest!

Comment: @RobertColumbia I'm "Thrilled" :)